# select in sql with specific format of date

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, datetime

I have a website project which selects dates from database. the database stores the date in this format "2013-01-02 00:00:00.000". but when I select the date, I want to use the format "11/06/2013" - "dd/mm/yyyy"

here is my select

```
-- I am trying to pass "dd/mm/yyyy"
select date from Currencies where date = '11/06/2013'
```

but this doesnt work. if I change my where clause as below, it works...

```
-- if I pass "mm/dd/yyyy" , it works
select date from Currencies where date = '06/11/2013'
```

but I must pass "dd/mm/yyyy", how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one

```
SELECT date FROM Currencies  WHERE date = convert(datetime, '11/06/2013 00:00:00', 103)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid handling variable syntax inside your sql statements and use parameterized queries instead

check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx) out.